# Using Script Task Editor in Visual Studio 2017 after update to Visual Studio 2017 SSDT no longer working

Tags: ssis, script-task

I am working on an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2017 SSDT.  I had an update come through for Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) Version 15.9.18 and it updated successfully.  I went to open one of my SSIS packages and when I opened the Script Task and clicked EDIT to the C# code I now get an error:  using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime; is no longer available.  What do I now use in its place so that I can continue working?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Dts.Runtime is actually contain by the assembly `Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS`. I haven't seen your issue before, though. Are your VS and SSDT installs in the default locations? Maybe SSDT moved the .dll? Or is expecting it to be somewhere it's not.

Comment: @digital.aaron, sorry for the late reply.  I was able to finally get it fixed as Microsoft moved the .dll file and I was able to fix the reference.  Thanks for your time in replying to my inquiry.